# Using Mma 9 is there a quicker way (using a keyboard combination or a button) to execute a Mma program than typing Alt+V and then O?

Tags: performance-tuning, button, user-interface

[Another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33197/keyboard-shortcut-to-evaluate-notebook) asks whether there is a keyboard shortcut for evaluating a notebook. The answer is yes. The quickest way that someone came up with was pressing Alt+V and then O, but the question did not ask for which way was fastest.

My question is different. I am asking whether there is a way that is faster than typing Alt+V and then O.

This might be another key combination, or it might be making a button that can be put at the top of the notebook. Getting a button which appears at the top of the code when the program is opened, and that I can click on to execute the whole thing, would be ideal.

Comment: "doesn't require compiling" - "Compiling" means something quite different from what you apparently think it means.

Comment: What's wrong with the answer in the linked question? It does exactly what you asked (assign a single key combination to "evaluate notebook")

Comment: First, I'm specifically asking for a faster way to do it than is given in that answer. The other question doesn't ask for the fastest way to do it. Second, the fastest way may not comprise a keyboard combination.

Comment: Thanks, J.M. - I will edit.

Comment: Please read the entire accepted answer to the linked question. It gives a way to specify any keyboard shortcut to evaluate the notebook, for example ctrl + h, which is faster than your current method.

Comment: Many people would consider a button to be slower than a keyboard shortcut. If that's what you prefer, though, it's addressed in this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138902/toolbar-button-or-permanent-palette-button-for-evaluate, which you can find by searching for "button evaluate" on mathematica s.e.