# How do I prevent 'Save changes to' upon closing a custom palette?

Tags: save, palettes

As part of a package I am developing, I am programmatically generating palettes to enter symbols using the CreatePalette function. Because those symbols change completely from application to application, I never have a need to save that palette to disk. Is there a way to set up the palette so that upon closing it, I never get the dialog box asking if I want to save it?

Minimal example:

```
CreatePalette[
   Column[PasteButton@@@{{Symbola,a},{Symbolb,b},{Symbolc,c}}],
   WindowTitle -> "Example"];
```

To get the behavior I am trying to eliminate, move the palette from its original location and then click the x to close it.

Comment: Add Saveable -> False?

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! I figured there would be a simple option, but for some reason was unable to find it.

Comment: @KevinAusman you can also add ``System`ClosingSaveDialog->False`` if you'd like to retain `Saveable` (e.g. for the `{"MenuCommand", "Save"}` event binding) but not have it ask you.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138925/3066) helpful.